# Sprites not appearing in pygame on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I have a pygame game, and it works perfectly fine on my laptop, but when I move it over to my raspberry pi, a lot of the sprites don't appear.  They are there because I can still click on them, but they don't seem to actually be being drawn.  I thought it may have been because the pi couldn't handle hundreds of pngs, so I compressed them all, and still no different results.  It's not the same sprites every time that don't appear.  If I relaunch the script, or even just refresh a screen, it's different images that decide to appear.  I then drew it to a capacitive tft screen from Adafruit, and it's still the same results.  The mouse is also inverted which is a bit annoying, but that is a different problem I will figure out.  The sprites are definitely there because I can still click them, they just aren't visible, like it can't load the image, but it doesn't give an error.

```
import pygame
class base_sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, color=(0,0,0), width=0, height=0, image=None,x=0,y=0, scale=None):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            if "Surface" in type(image).__name__:
                self.image = image
            else:
                self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
            if scale != None:
                self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (scale[0], scale[1]))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [5000000,5000000,width,height])
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = x
            self.rect.y = y

pygame.init()
width = 320
height = 240
s = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
inventoryGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

back = base_sprite(width=320, height=240, image="images/back.png", x=0, y=0)

headBorder = base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/ItemBorder.png", x=180, y=10, scale=[50, 50])
handBorder = base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/ItemBorder.png", x=250, y=94, scale=[50, 50])
bodyBorder = base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/ItemBorder.png", x=180, y=94, scale=[50, 50])
feetBorder = base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/ItemBorder.png", x=180, y=178, scale=[50, 50])
spellBorder = base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/ItemBorder.png", x=110, y=10, scale=[50, 50])
symbol =  base_sprite(width=100, height=100, image="images/mageSmall.png", x=5, y=(height/2)-50)

gameGroup.add(back)

inInventory = False
running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_i:
                inInventory = not inInventory

    gameGroup.draw(s)
    if inInventory:
        inventoryGroup.add(back)
        inventoryGroup.add(symbol)
        inventoryGroup.add(headBorder)
        inventoryGroup.add(handBorder)
        inventoryGroup.add(bodyBorder)
        inventoryGroup.add(feetBorder)
        inventoryGroup.add(spellBorder)
        inventoryGroup.add(base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/items/BasicHat.png", x=180, y=10, scale=[50, 50]))
        inventoryGroup.add(base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/items/BasicThingToHitPeopleWith.png", x=250, y=94, scale=[50, 50]))
        inventoryGroup.add(base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/items/BasicShirt.png", x=180, y=94, scale=[50, 50]))
        inventoryGroup.add(base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/items/BasicShoes.png", x=180, y=178, scale=[50, 50]))
        inventoryGroup.add(base_sprite(width=64, height=64, image="images/items/BasicBook.png", x=110, y=10, scale=[50, 50]))
        inventoryGroup.draw(s)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what can cause the problem without a [mcve] (and maybe a screenshot).

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Here is a link to a gif of the problem https://imgur.com/a/z43v0Y3.  As you can see, not all of the buttons are loading in during the first few screens, and once I get past that, different sprites load in every time I toggle the inventory.  Sorry I didn't include any code, I'm dumb.  I'll add that really quick.

Comment: It seems like you're adding the same sprites to the `inventoryGroup` every frame `inInventory` is `True`. Try having them before the game loop instead and only have `inventoryGroup.draw(s)` in the game loop instead. Don't know if it will fix the problem but it seems to be something that could cause problems.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman That doesn't fix it.  In the full game I have a var called newInventory that turns on every button press then in the game loop draws the screen and sets itself to false so it only adds the sprites once.  I took that out for the small version, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Does the version in the question exhibit the same problem?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman The gif I linked was of the full game so that has the problem, and the code above has the same problem.  I thought maybe it was from all the images (hundreds), I was loading in the full game, but the mini version has the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know what's causing the issue

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you're actually trying to do in your game? We need to understand the program if we should debug it.

Comment: @skrx Yeah, now I’m just trying to get sprites to work at all.  I did some testing and no matter what, when I try to draw a sprite group in pygame on raspberry pi b+ running python 3.5, the sprites will just sometimes not show up.  I got python 3.6 because that is what I’m running on my laptop where it works, but I can’t find a supported version of pygame to actually work.  The problem is still the same as I described above and what appears in the video, except it’s much not broad than I thought.  It happens whenever I draw a sprite group.

Answer (score -1):

I have to agree. This is a foolproof way fo solving your problem, and it is the simplest way to circumvent dealing with rendering issues. Here is some code of mine with no sprites:

```
 import pygame

pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))


# fixed variables at the start
x_pos = 400
y_pos = 400
current_speed = 15

def jump_coords(y_position, speed):
    if speed >= 0:
        #to move up, reduce the y-coordinate
        y_position -= speed
    return y_position

game_exit = False

# main loop
while not game_exit: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_pos = jump_coords(y_pos, current_speed)
                # 1 represents gravity value
                current_speed -= 1

    rect_one = pygame.Rect(x_pos, y_pos, 10, 10)  
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, (255, 0, 0), rect_one)
    pygame.display.update()`enter code here`
```